# Ubuntu 20.04 GUI not working, unable to install gnome-shell because of dependency errors

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, startup

Background: I installed deps trying to get a Rust game engine working.
During the process, I saw my icons on left side tabbar flick out for my browser, replaced with a standard icon.
I resolved the dependency issues, got the game engine running.

On reboot, I got a TTY and logged in manually. apt get update, autoremove, dkpgs commands later, I tried installing lightdm. That broke my system further, as now the system gets stuck on loading screen. Ctrl+alt+f3 brings me to a blinking cursor.

Using escape on startup, I can enter recovery mode for linux 6. I'm logged in as root and unable to install `gnome-shell`, which I think I need to restore my GUI.

gnome-shell depends: evolution-data-server (>= 3.33.1) but it is not goign to be installed.. same for gnome-settingfs-daemon, libpulse-mainloop-glib0

Trying to install the lastone, "unmet dependencies: libpulse-mainloop-lglib0: Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems

How do I fix this dependency hell and restore my ability to login through a GUI?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details (*most packages are built for specific releases*); but looking up a single package (`libpulse0 | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13      | focal-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` which you'll note is newer than your message) shows you're likely suffering as a result of careless & outdated sources being added.  You mention linux 6 (Ubuntu 23.04 uses the 6.2 kernel) but packages do **not** match that release so please be specific.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. If it does not work, reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc sorry, 20.04 ubuntu. I think it was 6.2 from safemode. Currently copying files out of my home directory o a USB, I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: @guiverc I checked my source list - I had a few duplicates of archive.ubuntu -- will check again

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi already tried the --reinstall and reinstalling the OS is *exactly& what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @guiverc everything above the PPA section hasn't worked so far, I'll try reviewing & purging PPAs next

Comment: I'd always started by updating your machines software lists; ie. `sudo apt update` and peruse the output looking for any issues (*things that don't match your release*), missing lines etc..   Your provided line matched `libpulse0 | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8       | focal-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` but not the latest found in `libpulse0 | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13      | focal-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`  ..

Comment: where as the wanted package was on original media (`libpulse0 | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3         | focal           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`)  ... ie. those lines just from a CLI enquiry on my system (`rmadison libpulse0`), but show a possible outdated repository issue, source issue etc..  (You can also explore packages online, ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpulse0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all would show most of the detail I got at terminal)

Comment: Great tip, I will try that thank you